# I would love to convert SVG XML into my own website name?

Tags: html, css, xml

I found some super cool code for generating a text logo and wanted to get that into my own website but I have no clue how to do such thing or how to set it up.

It would be awesome if I can get some help with that!

```
<svg class="tw-fill-current tw-text-white" width="232" height="44" viewBox="0 0 323 36" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <path
            d="M0 4.83h6.986v24.521h15.137v5.699H0V4.83zm53.374 23.744H39.36l-2.674 6.476h-7.159L42.981 4.83h6.9L63.38 35.05h-7.33l-2.675-6.476zm-2.199-5.31l-4.787-11.57-4.787 11.57h9.574zM92.949 35.05l-5.822-8.418H80.7v8.418h-6.986V4.83h13.067c2.674 0 4.995.446 6.965 1.339 1.969.892 3.485 2.158 4.55 3.799 1.063 1.64 1.595 3.583 1.595 5.828s-.54 4.18-1.617 5.806c-1.078 1.626-2.61 2.871-4.593 3.734l6.77 9.714H92.95zm-.13-19.254c0-1.698-.546-3-1.638-3.907-1.093-.907-2.688-1.36-4.787-1.36H80.7v10.534h5.693c2.099 0 3.694-.461 4.787-1.382 1.092-.92 1.638-2.216 1.638-3.885zm39.661 12.778h-14.016l-2.673 6.476h-7.16l13.456-30.22h6.9l13.498 30.22h-7.331l-2.674-6.476zm-2.2-5.31l-4.786-11.57-4.787 11.57h9.574zm36.556 12.304c-3.076 0-5.858-.67-8.344-2.008-2.487-1.338-4.442-3.194-5.865-5.569-1.424-2.374-2.135-5.058-2.135-8.05 0-2.994.711-5.678 2.135-8.052 1.423-2.375 3.378-4.231 5.865-5.57 2.486-1.338 5.282-2.007 8.387-2.007 2.617 0 4.981.46 7.094 1.382 2.114.92 3.889 2.245 5.326 3.971l-4.485 4.145c-2.04-2.36-4.57-3.54-7.59-3.54-1.868 0-3.536.41-5.002 1.23a8.742 8.742 0 0 0-3.429 3.432c-.819 1.468-1.229 3.137-1.229 5.008 0 1.87.41 3.54 1.23 5.008a8.742 8.742 0 0 0 3.428 3.432c1.466.82 3.134 1.23 5.002 1.23 3.02 0 5.55-1.194 7.59-3.583l4.485 4.145c-1.437 1.755-3.22 3.093-5.347 4.014-2.128.921-4.5 1.382-7.116 1.382zm73.888 0c-2.387 0-4.694-.324-6.922-.971-2.228-.648-4.018-1.49-5.369-2.526l2.372-5.267c1.294.95 2.832 1.713 4.614 2.288 1.783.576 3.565.864 5.348.864 1.984 0 3.45-.295 4.399-.885.948-.59 1.423-1.375 1.423-2.353 0-.72-.28-1.317-.841-1.792-.56-.475-1.28-.856-2.156-1.144-.877-.288-2.063-.604-3.558-.95-2.3-.546-4.183-1.093-5.65-1.64a9.178 9.178 0 0 1-3.773-2.633c-1.05-1.21-1.574-2.82-1.574-4.836 0-1.755.474-3.345 1.423-4.77.949-1.425 2.38-2.554 4.29-3.389 1.913-.834 4.249-1.252 7.009-1.252 1.926 0 3.81.23 5.65.691 1.84.46 3.45 1.122 4.83 1.986l-2.157 5.31c-2.789-1.583-5.578-2.375-8.366-2.375-1.955 0-3.4.317-4.334.95-.935.633-1.402 1.468-1.402 2.504s.54 1.806 1.617 2.31c1.078.503 2.724 1 4.938 1.49 2.3.546 4.183 1.093 5.65 1.64a9.355 9.355 0 0 1 3.773 2.59c1.05 1.18 1.574 2.777 1.574 4.792a8.258 8.258 0 0 1-1.445 4.727c-.963 1.425-2.408 2.554-4.334 3.389-1.926.835-4.27 1.252-7.03 1.252zm30.604-25.04h-9.66V4.83h26.306v5.699h-9.66v24.52h-6.986V10.53zm37.289 25.04c-2.386 0-4.694-.324-6.922-.971-2.228-.648-4.017-1.49-5.369-2.526l2.372-5.267c1.294.95 2.832 1.713 4.615 2.288 1.782.576 3.564.864 5.347.864 1.984 0 3.45-.295 4.399-.885.949-.59 1.423-1.375 1.423-2.353 0-.72-.28-1.317-.841-1.792-.56-.475-1.28-.856-2.156-1.144-.877-.288-2.063-.604-3.558-.95-2.3-.546-4.183-1.093-5.65-1.64a9.178 9.178 0 0 1-3.773-2.633c-1.05-1.21-1.574-2.82-1.574-4.836 0-1.755.474-3.345 1.423-4.77.949-1.425 2.38-2.554 4.291-3.389 1.912-.834 4.248-1.252 7.008-1.252 1.926 0 3.81.23 5.65.691 1.84.46 3.45 1.122 4.83 1.986l-2.157 5.31c-2.789-1.583-5.577-2.375-8.366-2.375-1.955 0-3.4.317-4.334.95-.935.633-1.402 1.468-1.402 2.504s.54 1.806 1.617 2.31c1.078.503 2.724 1 4.938 1.49 2.3.546 4.183 1.093 5.65 1.64a9.355 9.355 0 0 1 3.773 2.59c1.05 1.18 1.574 2.777 1.574 4.792a8.258 8.258 0 0 1-1.445 4.727c-.963 1.425-2.407 2.554-4.334 3.389-1.926.835-4.27 1.252-7.03 1.252z"
            fill="#FFF" fill-rule="nonzero" />
        <g fill="#FFF">
            <path
                d="M192.912 8.921l4.923 4.924a2.597 2.597 0 0 1-3.673 3.673l-4.923-4.924a2.597 2.597 0 1 1 3.673-3.673zM203.437 19.447l10.547 10.547a2.597 2.597 0 0 1-3.673 3.673L199.764 23.12a2.597 2.597 0 1 1 3.673-3.673z" />
            <path
                d="M190.416 8.255L218.753.893A2.672 2.672 0 0 1 222 2.767a2.592 2.592 0 0 1-1.846 3.199l-28.338 7.362a2.672 2.672 0 0 1-3.247-1.875 2.592 2.592 0 0 1 1.847-3.198z" />
            <path
                d="M209.592 31.104l7.363-28.337A2.592 2.592 0 0 1 220.153.92a2.672 2.672 0 0 1 1.875 3.247l-7.362 28.337a2.592 2.592 0 0 1-3.199 1.847 2.672 2.672 0 0 1-1.875-3.247z" />
        </g>
        <path
            d="M208.62 18.067l-10.236 10.235a2.643 2.643 0 1 1-3.738-3.738l10.236-10.235a2.643 2.643 0 0 1 3.738 3.738zM193.38 33.306l-1.54 1.54a2.643 2.643 0 1 1-3.738-3.738l1.54-1.54a2.643 2.643 0 0 1 3.738 3.738z"
            fill="#53B5FF" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: See if this can help [link](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_svg.asp). And your svg has no opening tag too.

Comment: I see yes I forgot to put the opening tag in.

This SVG shows the logo Laracasts but what if I for example would want to make that say BBGuru?

I have no clue how to do that and those links don't really explain it either :(

Comment: https://laracasts.com/

Look in the code of this website there it shows the SVG code used for the logo but how would I do such thing with for example BBGuru

Comment: SVG does not work like that, you can change the color, make some small chages,  animate, but i think you have to develop your own logo, then save in svg, it will be easier, i think.

Comment: See [***Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/290085).

Comment: are you looking for that question: "how to create svg?" You may google it. And find all answers. SO is not a place for such questions.

Comment: SVG can contain many layers.  And the layers can be URLs to graphic files and one can be an icon.